# Help with malloc and free: Glibc detected: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, free, malloc

I need help with debugging this piece of code. I know the problem is in malloc and free but can't find exactly where, why and how to fix it. Please don't answer: "Use gdb" and that's it. I would use gdb to debug it, but I still don't know much about it and am still learning it, and would like to have, in the meanwhile, another solution.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH  256
#define MAX_ARGS_NUMBER     128
#define MAX_HISTORY_NUMBER  100

#define PROMPT ">>> "

int num_elems;

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

typedef struct {
    char **arg;     
    char *infile;   
    char *outfile;  
    int background; 
} Command_Info;

int parse_cmd(char *cmd_line, Command_Info *cmd_info)
{
    char *arg;
    char *args[MAX_ARGS_NUMBER];    

    int i = 0;
    arg = strtok(cmd_line, " ");
    while (arg != NULL) {
        args[i] = arg;
        arg = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    num_elems = i;precisa em free_mem
    if (num_elems == 0)
        return 0;

    cmd_info->arg = (char **) ( malloc(num_elems * sizeof(char *)) );
    cmd_info->infile = NULL;
    cmd_info->outfile = NULL;
    cmd_info->background = 0;

    bool b_infile = false;
    bool b_outfile = false;

    int iarg = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elems; i++)
    {                   
        if ( !strcmp(args[i], "<") )
        {               
            if ( b_infile || i == num_elems-1 || !strcmp(args[i+1], "<") || !strcmp(args[i+1], ">") || !strcmp(args[i+1], "&") )
                return -1;                      

            i++;
            cmd_info->infile = malloc(strlen(args[i]) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(cmd_info->infile, args[i]);
            b_infile = true;
        }

        else if (!strcmp(args[i], ">"))
        {
            if ( b_outfile || i == num_elems-1 || !strcmp(args[i+1], ">") || !strcmp(args[i+1], "<") || !strcmp(args[i+1], "&") )
                return -1;

            i++;    
            cmd_info->outfile = malloc(strlen(args[i]) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(cmd_info->outfile, args[i]);
            b_outfile = true;
        }

        else if (!strcmp(args[i], "&"))
        {
            if ( i == 0 || i != num_elems-1 || cmd_info->background )
                return -1;

            cmd_info->background = true;
        }

        else
        {
            cmd_info->arg[iarg] = malloc(strlen(args[i]) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(cmd_info->arg[iarg], args[i]);
            iarg++;
        }
    }

    cmd_info->arg[iarg] = NULL; 

    return 0;
}


void print_cmd(Command_Info *cmd_info)
{
    int i;  
    for (i = 0; cmd_info->arg[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("arg[%d]=\"%s\"\n", i, cmd_info->arg[i]);
    printf("arg[%d]=\"%s\"\n", i, cmd_info->arg[i]);    
    printf("infile=\"%s\"\n", cmd_info->infile);
    printf("outfile=\"%s\"\n", cmd_info->outfile);
    printf("background=\"%d\"\n", cmd_info->background);
}

void get_cmd(char* str)
{
    fgets(str, MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH, stdin);
    str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
}

pid_t exec_simple(Command_Info *cmd_info)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork Error");
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if ( (execvp(cmd_info->arg[0], cmd_info->arg)) == -1)
        {
            perror(cmd_info->arg[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return pid;
}

void type_prompt(void)
{
    printf("%s", PROMPT);
}

void syntax_error(void)
{
    printf("msh syntax error\n");
}

void free_mem(Command_Info *cmd_info)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; cmd_info->arg[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(cmd_info->arg[i]);
    free(cmd_info->arg);
    free(cmd_info->infile);
    free(cmd_info->outfile);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char cmd_line[MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH];
    Command_Info cmd_info;
    //char* history[MAX_HISTORY_NUMBER];

    while (true)
    {   
        type_prompt();

        get_cmd(cmd_line);

        if ( parse_cmd(cmd_line, &cmd_info) == -1)
        {
            syntax_error();
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(cmd_line, ""))
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(cmd_info.arg[0], "exit"))
            exit(0);

        pid_t pid = exec_simple(&cmd_info);

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

        free_mem(&cmd_info);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: It doesn't say at which line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since strings in C are null-terminated, their actuall size in memory is length+1, so instead of

```
cmd_info->infile = malloc(strlen(args[i]) * sizeof(char));
```

You should have

```
cmd_info->infile = malloc((strlen(args[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
```

EDIT: As Aeth said, you need to change every single occurence of malloc to contain space for that additional null character:

```
cmd_info->arg = (char **) ( malloc(num_elems * sizeof(char *)) ); //this one can stay, since it determines number of strings, not string length
cmd_info->outfile = malloc((strlen(args[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
cmd_info->arg[iarg] = malloc((strlen(args[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: I have changed that, but still get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Please help. Question edited.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658648/help-with-malloc-and-free-glibc-detected-free-invalid-pointer/2658703#2658703) and see if you are still having the same problems after doing the second step.

Answer (score 2):

When you are dynamically allocating memory for `cmd_info->infile` as:

```
cmd_info->infile = malloc(strlen(args[i]) * sizeof(char));
```

you are not allocating space for the terminating `null` char.

Same is the case with allocation for `cmd_info->outfile`

When you allocate space for `n` char and copy a string of length `n` into it, I think that overwrites the metadata that `malloc` maintains at the end of the array and this bug shows up when you call `free` to deallocate the memory as free does not find that meta data.

**EDIT:**

Change:

```
num_elems = i;
```

to

```
num_elems = i+1;
```

Since you are marking the end of the arguments with `NULL`

```
cmd_info->arg[iarg] = NULL;
```

you need to allocate the space for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to allocate an extra `char` for each of your strings to handle the terminating null.

   cmd_info->arg[iarg] = malloc((strlen(args[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
2. You need to allocate an additional `char*` in the `cmd_info->arg` array.  This extra element will store the `NULL` that signifies the end of the array of arguments.

   cmd_info->arg = (char **) ( malloc((num_elems+1) * sizeof(char *)) );

---

I have confirmed on my system that the program successfully frees all its memory without error after both of the changes listed were made.

Comment: +1, yes those two change should fix the program. Good findings :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this error is usually the result of something writing data outside a `malloc()`'d block (off the end or before the beginning).  This can corrupt the memory allocator's internal bookkeeping structures.

Others have already pointed out the particular problem in your code.  In cases where it's more deeply hidden, I have found [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to be useful for debugging.  At the expense of noticable code slowdown, it is able to detect illegal memory accesses (in the form of "invalid reads" and "invalid writes") at a very fine-grained level.  Memory debuggers such as [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com) can also be helpful, and don't impose nearly as much overhead, but in my experience aren't quite as good as Valgrind for finding everything.

Valgrind, in its 'memcheck' mode, will output memory access errors with a stack trace of where in the program they occurred.  Usually, when I have an "invalid pointer" error in `free()`, it will be preceeded at some point by an invalid write which memcheck will find.